# Blank page when attempting to view pdf along with numerous "ignoring invalid character in hex string" warnings

Tags: angular, pdf, ionic-framework, ionic3, pdf.js

I'm not sure where else to turn on this issue. It's been plaguing me all weekend.

I have an Ionic 3 application and i'm using ng2-pdf-viewer library for handling pdfs (i believe this library is based on pdf.js, but just geared more toward Angular usage).

I originally posted this issue on the github issues page for this particular library, but I'm not sure how active the threads there might get: https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/issues/387.

Essentially my problem is this. When I try to view a pdf using the 'pdf-viewer' component from the library I am getting a whole bunch of warnings in the Chrome dev console...

**"Ignoring invalid character n in hex string"**
where n seems to be the same set of values no matter what the source of the pdf is...'character "33", character "79", character "84", character "89" etc. etc.'

There are dozens of these warnings and all I'm getting when attempting to view the pdf is a blank page.

The odd thing here is that everything works just perfectly on Firefox, but in Chrome and, more importantly, on ios/android devices themselves, I get the warning errors with a blank page.

Anyone who can help out here would be most appreciated!

Comment: I don't care if people downvote, but if you do please let me know why so my questions can be better in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on doing it this way actually and ended up just removing this library and using http request with file uri from server to get file as responseType blob, saving file locally to file system, and then using either fileopener plugin on mobile or window.open on web app to view. It actually works for all file types too and not just pdfs. If anyone else runs into an issue I can probably whip up an example for you.

Comment: Could you please help me with that same issue, except I am using React?!